# Is there a legal deadline for when your bank/brokerage has to send your tax forms to you?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, taxes

It is mid February and I still haven't received my 1099-div forms from my stock broker. Should I be concerned yet? Is there any regulatory requirement for them to send tax forms out to account holders by a specific date in the US?

Comment: I am using Schwab too and although I don't remember getting this letter, I did see it when I logged into my online account and sure enough my forms were available for download. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got notice from Charles Schwab that the forms weren't being mailed out until the middle of February because, for some reason, the forms were likely to change and rather than mail them out twice, they mailed them out once.

Perhaps some state tax laws took effect (such as two Oregon bills regarding tax rates for higher incomes) and they waited on that.

While I haven't gotten my forms mailed to me yet, I did go online and get the electronic copies that allowed me to finish my taxes already.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the custodians (ie. Schwab) file for an extension on 1099s.  They file for an extension as many of their accounts have positions with foreign income which creates tax reporting issues.  If they did not file for extension they would have to send out 1099s at the end of January and then send out corrected forms.  Obviously sending out one 1099 is cheaper and less confusing to all.

Hope that helps,

Comment: +1.  This is exactly what the emails from Schwab said to me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find specific information for Form 1099-DIV for this tax year.  However, I found this quote for *next* tax season that talks about Form 1099-B:

> Due date for certain statements sent to recipients.
>   The due date for furnishing statements to recipients for
>   Forms **1099-B**, 1099-S, and 1099-MISC (if amounts are
>   reported in box 8 or 14) is [February 15, 2018](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099gi.pdf). [emphasis added]

I know many brokerages bundle the 1099-DIV with the 1099-B, so one might assume that the deadlines are the same.  February 15 seems consistent with the messages I got from my brokerages that said the forms will be mailed by mid-February.

Comment: My broker even states that for 2018 1099 will be provied on Febr 18th!