# If a broker in the US does not provide Form 1099 by its due date (January 31), what penalty do they face, and can the client be compensated?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, brokerage, form-1099

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/form1099div.asp ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130052351/https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/form1099div.asp)) says:

> Banks, investment companies, and other financial institutions are required to provide taxpayers with a 1099-DIV by Jan. 31 each year.

However, I see in my Fidelity brokerage account that the Form 1099-DIV is not available yet:

> We're waiting for final tax information from multiple issuers. Your form is delayed because we're waiting for information from ISHARES CALIFORNIA MUNI BOND ETF(CMF), VANGUARD WHITEHALL FDS HIGH DIV YLD(VYM), and 3 more issuers. We'll email you as soon as this form is available.

[image]

[image]

If a broker in the US does not provide Form 1099 by its due date (January 31), what penalty do they face, and can the client be compensated?

Comment: Compensation? What harm has been done to you if the form is delayed?

Comment: @BobBaerker not being able to file a return (and get a refund) in a timely manner; after all, my tax return is *very* complex.

Comment: Related: [When are 1099 Tax Forms Due?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/90979/10997)

Comment: Related: [Is there a legal deadline for when your bank/brokerage has to send your tax forms to you?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/999/10997)

Comment: Note that the IRS is not yet accepting tax filings anyway.

Comment: If they are waiting on information, would you rather that they send you a 1099 with incorrect information, and then send you an updated one later?

Comment: @Ron John - Again, the same question.  If your filing is delayed a week or two, what damages have been done to you, warranting compensation?

Comment: @BobBaerker I can't think of any; someone might.  (Really, though, I think this isn't a Civil issue but subject to regulatory punishment.)

Comment: UBS is consistently late in sending out their Forms 1099. It holds up taxpayers from filing their tax returns, and receiving their refunds which in some cases may be large amounts. Each day waiting equates to several more days of waiting for the IRS delayed refunds. UBS should be penalized and also compensate their customers for not meeting their required deadlines. It's just not fair!!

Comment: @BobBaerker One possibility is if your income was high in 2019 and 2021 but dropped in 2020, you want to get your 2020 return processed ASAP so any upcoming stimulus payments are based on your 2020 income.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like because it's a consolidated Form 1099 (including 1099-B information), they get the February 15 (February 16 this year) deadline instead of January 31 (February 1 this year). From the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099gi#idm140388153675040) (my **emphasis** added):

> Due date for certain statements sent to recipients. The due date for furnishing statements to recipients for Forms 1099-B, 1099-S, and 1099-MISC (if amounts are reported in box 8 or 10) is February 15, 2022. **This also applies to statements furnished as part of a consolidated reporting statement.**

And as your screenshot shows, Fidelity is waiting for information from other funds, so it's not entirely their fault. However, I share your frustration, as you can go to the `Tax Info (Year-to-Date)` tab of the account in question, and see exactly what your 1099 is going to show (including qualified dividends, section 199A dividends, foreign tax paid, etc.), so I'm not sure why they take so long.

Comment: Thanks, yes agreed, they seem to have all the information.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I suspect they are just waiting until the deadline in case they receive revised information from funds their clients hold. I doubt anybody picks a brokerage with speed of sending 1099s as a key consideration, so they have little incentive to provide them early. And of course the uproar will be far louder if they have to send out revised 1099s.

Comment: Well, my Fidelity account now predicts February 27 (I suspect yours does too @FranckDernoncourt), which is well past even the consolidated deadline...

Comment: Still Feb 13 on my side